# php do-while loop, check before every loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I hit an API to get values then load them into a MySQL table, sometimes the values come back as 0 and simply re-running the API call will return the actual values. I figured a simple loop would work, but I can't seem to figure out how to re-check my $checkDigit, which would break the loop once a value which is greater than 0 is inserted into the table.

Is there any way to re-check or have a MySQL query within the while portion that runs on every loop? From this sample below, if the $checkDigit comes back as 0, it turns into an infinite loop since the query checking the DB value is only checked once in the beginning.

I thought a do-while loop would have been the cleanest method, but the only thing I can think of is nesting a bunch of if statements instead. Hopefully, I'm just overlooking something simple, but I haven't been able to find an example of a do-while loop with multiple checks.

```
<?php 
$sqlCheck = "select digits from table where date=current_date";
$result = $con->query($sqlCheck);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $checkDigit = $row['digits']; 
    }
}

do {
    //fetch JSON from API and load the digits value into table;
} while ($checkDigit < 1);
?>
```

Update:

So, this should technically work then?

executes the check query -> fetches the data from the api and loads it -> takes value from check query to see if it should exit -> if it has to run again it will re-run the check query to update the $checkDigit value -> hit the API again -> use new $checkDigit value to see if it should exit etc etc

```
<?php 

do {
$sqlCheck = "select digits from table where date=current_date";
$result = $con->query($sqlCheck);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $checkDigit = $row['digits']; 
    }
}
    //fetch JSON from API and load the digits value into table;
} while ($checkDigit < 1);
?>
```

Comment: yes, you can run queries in a loop. but note that any time you run nested queries, and the inner query uses/depends on data from the outer query, you probably can/should rewrite as a single [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)ed query.

Comment: Depending on the use cases, I try to hold off on doing the sub queries in a loop, and just compile a very large set of queries, then afterwards submit it as 1 giant transaction.  Example:   `$d = 0; $list=new array(); while($d < 5){  $list[] = "insert into table"}   $q = implode(";", $list); mysql_query($q);`

Comment: so, simply adding the check queries into the do portion of the loop should technically work, right? (even though it might not be the best solution)

Comment: You can do that yes but it can be a huge wasting of optimization

Comment: yeah, i figured as much - i think i'll need to explore some different methods - i would imagine it would be better to check the JSON values before ever interacting with my DB